# Bamboo NUnit Parser Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found

Tags: nunit, bamboo, nunit-console

My bamboo build NUnit Runner task is creating the following result file:
${bamboo.build.working.directory}\bld-output\${bamboo.ACM.AssemblyInformationalVersion}\ACCCMApplication\TestResult.xml

But my NUnit Parser bamboo task (which is the next running task) is failing logging

```
build   06-Nov-2018 06:48:46    Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 2.6861236 seconds
build   06-Nov-2018 06:48:46      Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
build   06-Nov-2018 06:48:46    
simple  06-Nov-2018 06:48:46    Parsing test results under D:\build-dir\ACM-NUNITINT-JOB1...
simple  06-Nov-2018 06:48:46    Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.
```

I have tried the following options in the NUnit Parser task for NUnit Test Results File/Directory with no success. What is the correct way to format the path to this xml? :

```
${bamboo.build.working.directory}\bld-output\${bamboo.ACM.AssemblyInformationalVersion}\ACCCMApplication\TestResult.xml
**/bld-output/${bamboo.ACM.AssemblyInformationalVersion}/ACCCMApplication/TestResult.xml
**/test-reports/*.xml
${bamboo.build.working.directory}/bld-output/${bamboo.ACM.AssemblyInformationalVersion}/ACCCMApplication/TestResult.xml (with outside build checked)
```

Comment: Even when running on Windows, those paths are case-sensitive. Double-check that the directory and file names match. Also, inspect the `D:\build-dir\ACM-NUNITINT-JOB1` directory to check whether the file you expect is actually present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end made it as simple as possible.
The NUnit Runner configuration Result Filename was left at the root directory (i.e  TestResult.xml)
And the NUnit Parser configuration NUnit Test Results File was set to **/TestResult.xml